# Извлечь данные из JSON, приходящие в ответе POST запроса, на языке Lua

Tags: json, post, lua

Занимаюсь нагрузочным тестированием. Пишу скрипт в Load Impact на языке Lua. Столкнулся со следующей проблемой:
Есть запрос POST. В этом запросе в Response приходят данные в JSON формате:
[image: Ответ в POST запросе]

http://myscreenshot.info/i/0006/612111450699792884956751912612.png

Вопрос:
Как мне извлечь эти данные? Например, мне нужно значение локальной переменной присвоить значение "ID".

Comment: С таким запросом не искал. Буду искать дальше. У меня проблема в том, что я не понимаю как мне обратиться к этому ответу. Есть ли какая-нибудь штука, позволяющая стразу обращаться к данным, приходящим в response.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без проверок на nil:

```
local response = http.post(url)   -- или response = http.request("POST", url ...    
local j = json.parse( response.body )
print(1, j.Id )
-- или так 
print(2, response.body:match('"Id":"(.-)"') )
```